# Why FocusManager doesn't work inside AlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Does anyone knows how can I show or hide the keyboard inside `AlertDialog`?

The `focusManager.clearFocus()` doesn't work inside `AlertDialog`.

Same for `textInputService?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()` and `softwareKeyboardController?.hide()`.

For example:

```
AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = {
        openDialog.value = false
    },
    text = {
        TextField(...)
    }
    buttons = {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
        ) {
            Text("Update")
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Please add your code. How are you trying to hide the keyboard?

Comment: @SK.Fuad added sample code, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AlertDialog`, as any other `Dialog`, has its own `LocalFocusManager` as well as some other local constants.

You are capturing its value outside of `AlertDialog`, instead you need to capture it inside:

```
buttons = {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
    ) {
        Text("Update")
    }
}
```